# Trigonometry from integration (simplifying)

Tags: trigonometry

How do I simplify $$\frac14\sin(2\arccos(x))$$
to $$\frac12x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Note, it used to more complex I simplified it to this level, I think you have to use a triangle but im not sure...

Thank you,
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

If you let $\theta = \cos^{-1}(x)$, you can use the fact that $\sin(2\theta) = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$. You then need to write $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ in terms of $x$ in order to get the result you are looking for (and you can certainly use a triangle to help with that part).

Comment: but then how do I find sin(arccos(x)) to equal  {\sqrt{1-x^2}}

Comment: That's where a right triangle is helpful. Let the hypotenuse be $1$ and one leg be $x$. The angle between those sides is $\cos^{-1}(x)$, and the sine of that angle is the length of the other leg. It's a very handy triangle to know; the angle opposite leg $x$ is $\sin^{-1}(x)$ so you can use it for arc-sine problems too.

Comment: Another way to look at it is, "If only it were arc sine instead of arc cosine, I would know the answer." So you ask yourself, "arc cosine of $x$ is arc sine of what?" The triangle is just an aid to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2y+\cos^2y =1 \implies \sin y= \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^22y} \tag{1}$
$\sin 2y=2\sin y\cos y \tag{2}$  .
Using $1$ and $2$:

$\sin(2(\arccos(x))=2\sin(\arccos x)\cos(\arccos x)=\pm2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos x)}\times\cos(\arccos x)$.

You know $\cos(\arccos(x))=x$

So

$\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos x)}\times\cos(\arccos x)=\pm\dfrac{1}{2} x\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: where did u get {\pm2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos x)} this from?

Comment: @user124203 Are you talking of the latex? see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know *[duplication rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae)*? Then ot's really *trivial* to prove the identity...
$$\frac14\sin(2\arccos(x))\\=\frac14 2\sin(\arccos(x))\cos(\arccos(x))\\=\frac12 x\sqrt{1-[\cos(\arccos(x))]^2}=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\arccos x=y\implies x=\cos y$ and from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $0\le y\le\pi\implies\sin y\ge0$

$\displaystyle\implies\sin y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

and subsequently   $\displaystyle\sin(2\arccos x)=\sin2y=2\sin y\cos y=\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

your stategy is 2-fold.

1) eliminate the 2arccos(x)s by using a double angle identity

2) re-express any tan(arccos(x))s or sin(arccos(x))s as cos(arccos(x))s

as you go through some of the other answers, keep these strategies in mind.